# Android Icon Cannot Be Shown

Tags: android

I am new to learn Android programming. I follow the book, Android Programming the Big Nerd Ranch Guide. I think it is a good tutorial.

When I read the Chapter 16, the Action Bar, I noticed that the icons of all of my applications I learned from the book could not be shown on my Nexus 5.

I check from the 1st step by step. I believe I didn't make any mistakes.

I also follow [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html), to test. Unfortunately, the icon for the Hello World sample cannot be shown either.

Could someone please give me a hand?

I was told that the AndroidManifest.xml could be wrong. The one of mine is listed as follows. This is the hello world sample from https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html.

Since the sample is simple, I didn't make any updates to all of the XMLs and java code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.greatfree.test.myfirstapp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The following lines are MyActivity.java.

```
package com.greatfree.test.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The below one is the activity_my.xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add your code, so that we can see what you have done.  As many things could be wrong, ie. if you are using fragments, you have set `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer by Google.

The following lines should be added to MyActivity.java. I was told that API 21 got something incompatible.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Next time try to explain your problem in detail. It wasn't clear if you were talking about app icon shown on the launcher/shortcut or something else.

Answer (score 0):

The below link answered my question. Thanks!

http://forums.udacity.com/questions/100235173/app-icon-not-showing-in-the-title-bar?sort=votes&page=1#ud853